# PYQT After Timeline Animation

Tags: animation, pyqt5

I have a lottery program which is written by python(PYQT5). Now,I got the lucky number in the back first and roll the label. I want to paste the answer finally. Like code.

```
r_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #random list
animation(label,r_list,ans) #GUI showing

#GUI showing (label,random list,final text)
def animation(label,r_list,ans):
    show_timmer = 5 #time of animation(sec)
    #animation
    timeline = QtCore.QTimeLine(show_timmer * 1000, self) #time of timeline
    timeline.setFrameRange(label.geometry().top(), label.geometry().width()) #range of anumation
    timeline.setLoopCount(1) #action times
    timeline.frameChanged.connect(lambda: self.__set_frame_func(label,r_list)) #animation action
    timeline.start() #anumation start
    #finally:paste the answer

#anumation action:rolling label
def set_frame_func(label,r_list):
    msg = r_list[random.randint(0,len(r_list)-1)] #random text
    label.setText(msg) #change the text
    return
```

Accroding to the code, I try in vain to finish the code.

```
    #finally:paste the answer
    while True:
        if timeline.state() == 0:
            label.setText(ans)
            break
```

```
    #finally:paste the answer
    time.sleep(show_timmer)
    label.setText(ans)
```

```
    #finally:paste the answer
    start = time.time() 
    while True:
        if time.time() - start >= show_timmer:
            break
    label.setText(ans)
```

All the ways will crash the computer. Which case I can reference?

I'm poor at English. I'm sorry if I offend.

Comment: None of the three possibilities is valid, since all of them are blocking, starting the animation should be enough, what doesn't work with it?

Comment: Thanks for answering first.
Maybe I can't explain by my poor English. So that I make an example.
For example:
There are 0~9 in the box.
1. Let 8 is lucky number in the back first.
2. UI animation. (Roll the label to make the random feeling.)
3. UI show 8 in the end.
Accroding to the example , how to achieve step 3? In other words , how to "wait for animation" or "set the end in animation"?

Comment: Use the [`finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimeline.html#finished) signal.

Comment: Excused me. Would you provide examples for me? Maybe I'm poor at concept , too. Only three of ways can be though by myself. Therefore , how different with the first way? Or which one I need to advance more?

Comment: I already told you, ***NONE*** of those is valid. Connect the `finished` signal to a function that will show the final result. If you don't understand what I mean by "connect the signal", then I strongly urge you to go back and take some tutorials (start from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials)) to understand the fundamental elements of Qt, because you cannot go anywhere without that basic knowledge.